# Getting 404 URL not found on making SOAP request

Tags: php, soap

I'm having problem when trying to call SOAP service from my server , on trying i am getting 404 not found error, but when I am trying to access same through my local server (xampp) then it is showing correct result

Live URL

```
http://alphaomegahr.com/app/client_portal/CustomerAuthenticate.php
```

Soap Service URL is

```
http://alphaomegahr.com/app/vtigerservice.php?service=customerportal
```

I am also trying to access same through local server

```
http://localhost/app/client_portal/CustomerAuthenticate.php
```

It is loading fine

Please help me, I am badly stuck with this Problem

Edit 
I have just uploaded a simple curl code on server

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init(); // start CURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://alphaomegahr.com/app/vtigerservice.php"); // set your URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // get the response as a variable
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);      
    $response = curl_exec($ch); // connect and get your response 
    curl_close($ch);    
    print_r($response);
?>
```

It is returning /app/vtigerservice not found, but this url (http://alphaomegahr.com/app/vtigerservice.php) is opening properly through browser

Comment: is alphaomegahr.com on a virtual host? Have you tried including the host name in your fetch of `vtigerservice.php` inside `CustomerAuthenticate.php`?

Comment: Yes I am calling it directly through host name,